# CloudFormation Template Error when placing EC2 Instance in particular subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Working on a CF example template and am attempting to place an EC2 instance into a subnet created from the same template.  When doing things as is, I get this error:

```
The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet
```

Here's a subset of the template:

```
Resources:
VPC:
  Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
  Properties:
      CidrBlock: 172.34.0.0/16                                  
      EnableDnsHostnames: False
      Tags:
Subnet1:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
  Properties:
    AvailabilityZone: us-west-1a
    CidrBlock: 172.34.0.0/24
    VpcId: 
      Ref: VPC
    MapPublicIpOnLaunch: False
WebServer1:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties:
    ImageId: !FindInMap [RegionMap, !Ref "AWS::Region", AMI]
    InstanceType: t2.micro                                   
    SubnetId:
      Ref: Subnet1
    SecurityGroups: 
      - Ref: ServerSecurityGroup
    Tags:
      - Key: "Name"
        Value: "Tyler-Cloudformation"
```

How can I refer to `Subnet 1` when creating `WebServer1` and place it within that subnet? What am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably because you are using `SecurityGroups` rather then [SecurityGroupIds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-securitygroupids). The former parameter is only used for default-VPCs, while for non-default ones, the latter must be used.

Thus, instead of `SecurityGroups` you should have:

```
      SecurityGroupIds: 
        - !GetAtt ServerSecurityGroup.GroupId
```